# Removing fields with Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Usually to remove some fields from collections in MongoDB, `$unset` is used.  What can I do in Ruby to accomplish that? I have tried to read [this](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#remove-instance_method), but I couldn't understand how to use it. I am new to Ruby and still learning to work with it.

Comment: No just want to know in case. I am studying Ruby also so want to know how can I do it with Ruby.

Comment: $unset removes fields, and the ruby "remove" removes whole documents.  They are 2 different things.  Also the ruby client is just that, a client.  It wraps some things with ruby syntax, but you can still pass in mongo syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The `$unset` operator is used through the `update` command which is documented [here](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#update-instance_method) for the ruby driver.

Taking a step back, the standard (10gen-maintained) MongoDB Ruby driver can do absolutely everything that mongodb can.  It exposes very literally the full capabilities of mongodb, just like the mongodb drivers in other languages do.  So don't worry about being able to do mongo things in any particular language.

You might be wondering about the capabilities of popular ODM layers since they vary.  ODM layers map mongodb documents to native language objects.  In Ruby, [mongoid](http://mongoid.org/) is the most popular ODM.  As @Tilo points out, it also supports explicitly removing fields from documents through its higher-level API.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this issue for Mongoid:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/635

```
p = Product.first
p.raw_attributes.delete :foo
p.save
```